# Release memory in perl script

Tags: perl

I want all this combinations but I don't have enough memory. How can I release memory in my script?

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Algorithm::Combinatorics 'variations_with_repetition';

my @let = qw/ A G C T /;
my @cad = variations_with_repetition(\@let, 24);
print "@$_\n" for @cad;
```

Comment: [Relevant doc](http://search.cpan.org/~fxn/Algorithm-Combinatorics-0.27/Combinatorics.pm#variations_with_repetition%28\@data,_$k%29)

Comment: You should check that: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=108469

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to simply use `iterators`.
By assigning the results of `variations_with_repetition` to a scalar, it generates an iterator that you can interrogate each time to get the next element. By doing so, you don't keep the entire list in memory and you have access to the first elements immediately. This is a lovely concept called *lazy evaluation*. 
Here is the code for your case:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Algorithm::Combinatorics 'variations_with_repetition';

my @let = qw / A G C T/;
my $cad = variations_with_repetition(\@let,24);
while(my $c = $cad->next)
{
    print "@$c\n";
}
```

Just notice that the iterator actually returns a reference to an array that you have to dereference first and then join or do whatever operation you like on it.

*Testing Results:* I couldn't run the initial code on my machine (memory usage grows indefinitely as expected), but using iterators, I immediately started getting the output rows, with perl hardly consuming any memory.

Comment: I was trying with other code but your explanation seems clear:               `while (my $p = $iter->next) {
    my $result = join '', values $p;
       print "$result\n";
}`

Comment: Hah, much more straightforward than my solution. All along I was thinking, "hey, this library uses iterators internally, wouldn't it be nice if only it exposed them?" :).

Comment: Well, your solution is a very smart one in my opinion.  Also, I didn't know how to use the iterator version beforehand,  I found about it when I was trying to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well, enumerating words written on the alphabet (A, G, C, T) is much
the same as counting in base four. Knowing this (remove the call to
head; it's only there to truncate the very long output while testing):

```
{ echo 4o; seq 0 $((4 ** 24 - 1)) | sed 's/$/p/'; } | dc | awk '{ printf "%024d\n", $1 }' | tr 0-4 AGCT | head
```

Explanation:

- `echo 4o` is a command that instructs `dc` to output in base four;
- `seq` is asked to count over the entire range that 24-digit base-four number covers;
- `sed` appends a `p` to each line to ask `dc` to print each number (in base four, remember);
- `awk` prepends enough zeros to make the number print 24 digits;
- `tr` translates digits (0, 1, 2, 3) to the alphabet (A, G, C, T).